# Reading Infrared raw data

Tags: infrared

I'm trying to understand a few things about this code.

1. Why is `digitalRead()` slower than `IRpin_PIN & (1 << IRpin)`?
2. What does `IRpin_PIN & (1 << IRpin)` mean? I translated it to numbers and I figured out it's actually `PIND & (0b100)`. What does PIND translate to and why is bitwise-and with `0b100` performed on it?
3. Why is the 20-microsecond delay (`RESOLUTION`) necessary?
4. What does `_BV` in `while (! (IRpin_PIN & _BV(IRpin)))` mean?

---

```
/* Raw IR decoder sketch!

 This sketch/program uses the Arduno and a PNA4602 to 
 decode IR received. This can be used to make a IR receiver
 (by looking for a particular code)
 or transmitter (by pulsing an IR LED at ~38KHz for the
 durations detected 

 Code is public domain, check out www.ladyada.net and adafruit.com
 for more tutorials! 
 */

// We need to use the 'raw' pin reading methods
// because timing is very important here and the digitalRead()
// procedure is slower!
//uint8_t IRpin = 2;
// Digital pin #2 is the same as Pin D2 see
// http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168 for the 'raw' pin mapping
#define IRpin_PIN      PIND
#define IRpin          2

// the maximum pulse we'll listen for - 65 milliseconds is a long time
#define MAXPULSE 65000

// what our timing resolution should be, larger is better
// as its more 'precise' - but too large and you wont get
// accurate timing
#define RESOLUTION 20 

// we will store up to 100 pulse pairs (this is -a lot-)
uint16_t pulses[100][2];  // pair is high and low pulse 
uint8_t currentpulse = 0; // index for pulses we're storing

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Ready to decode IR!");
}

void loop(void) {
  uint16_t highpulse, lowpulse;  // temporary storage timing
  highpulse = lowpulse = 0; // start out with no pulse length
//  while (digitalRead(IRpin)) { // this is too slow!
    while (IRpin_PIN & (1 << IRpin)) {
     // pin is still HIGH
     // count off another few microseconds
     highpulse++;
     delayMicroseconds(RESOLUTION);
     // If the pulse is too long, we 'timed out' - either nothing
     // was received or the code is finished, so print what
     // we've grabbed so far, and then reset
     if ((highpulse >= MAXPULSE) && (currentpulse != 0)) {
       printpulses();
       currentpulse=0;
       return;
     }
  }
  // we didn't time out so let's stash the reading
  pulses[currentpulse][0] = highpulse;
  // same as above
  while (! (IRpin_PIN & _BV(IRpin))) {
     // pin is still LOW
     lowpulse++;
     delayMicroseconds(RESOLUTION);
     if ((lowpulse >= MAXPULSE)  && (currentpulse != 0)) {
       printpulses();
       currentpulse=0;
       return;
     }
  }
  pulses[currentpulse][1] = lowpulse;
  // we read one high-low pulse successfully, continue!
  currentpulse++;
}

void printpulses(void) {
  Serial.println("\n\r\n\rReceived: \n\rOFF \tON");
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < currentpulse; i++) {
    Serial.print(pulses[i][0] * RESOLUTION, DEC);
    Serial.print(" usec, ");
    Serial.print(pulses[i][1] * RESOLUTION, DEC);
    Serial.println(" usec");
  }
  // print it in a 'array' format
  Serial.println("int IRsignal[] = {");
  Serial.println("// ON, OFF ");
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < currentpulse-1; i++) {
    //Serial.print("\t"); // tab
    Serial.print("pulseIR(");
    Serial.print(pulses[i][1] * RESOLUTION , DEC);
    Serial.print(");");
    Serial.println("");
    //Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print("delayMicroseconds(");
    Serial.print(pulses[i+1][0] * RESOLUTION , DEC);
    Serial.println(");");
  }
  //Serial.print("\t"); // tab
  Serial.print("pulseIR(");
  Serial.print(pulses[currentpulse-1][1] * RESOLUTION, DEC);
  Serial.print(");");
}
```

Comment: I expect the source for digitalRead() will explain a lot about why it's slower.

Answer (score 1):

```
int digitalRead(uint8_t pin)
{
    uint8_t timer = digitalPinToTimer(pin);
    uint8_t bit = digitalPinToBitMask(pin);
    uint8_t port = digitalPinToPort(pin);

    if (port == NOT_A_PIN) return LOW;

    // If the pin that support PWM output, we need to turn it off
    // before getting a digital reading.
    if (timer != NOT_ON_TIMER) turnOffPWM(timer);

    if (*portInputRegister(port) & bit) return HIGH;
    return LOW;
}
```

1) so it

- calls function `digitalRead()` (puts value on stack, jumps, prepare function frame - each cost some time)
- calls 3 other functions (with all the same problems)
- check for sanity of value
- check for PWN (and eventually calls another function)
- does the `PIND & (0b100)`
- returns from function (so read stack, clear the frame, jumps, set the result)

just to obtain the same functionality

- typical for library functions, that each call makes sure the environment is sane and expected each and every time it is called - in close loop you can check it onece before and then just do not broke it
- translates parameter from `nice arduino numbers` to `real addresses and bits` each and every time again

2) it access the PORT D (see AVR (the processor) internal construction) and reads value of its 3. bit (which maps to the relevant pin of the chip/Arduino board

3) see following comment - it is expected length of the pulse (maybe with some safety limit)

4) _BV is for BitValue - shift 1 to position given by arg (that is macro doind 1 << IRpin) maybe more nice/readable version, compiles to the same. (the `!` is ofcourse negaition)